# How to compare a experimental cluster algorithm with expected results

Tags: r, algorithm, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

Which is the best method, to check how accurate a cluster algorithm is (in this case, K-Means)? I already know the true separation of groups, made by a more advanced algorithm.

However, I'm facing a wall. How can I identify that my group 1 is the same as theirs group 2? This could be done manually, if the separation was the same. But, as the results differ from each other, it seems not wort doing it "by hand", and it is better to take a CS approach/statistics.

Do you have any idea on which algorithm could I use, to solve this problem?

Please take a look at this two objects. The first is the expected separation of time series, and the second one is the way I group them.

Check the first 6 elements of both, and see that the group 3 in the expected data might be the same as *my* group 3. However, the *their* elements 4 and 5, that are in group 4 and 2, are inserted in *my* the group 6. Thus, how can I identify if my group 6 is their 2 or 4, so I can compute the percentage of hits.

```
c(3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 
6L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
4L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 
6L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
3L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 
6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 
4L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 
3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
6L)
```

--

```
c(3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2, 1, 1, 6, 6, 3, 6, 
2, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 6, 2, 6, 6, 2, 2, 1, 6, 1, 6, 2, 6, 6, 2, 6, 
6, 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 6, 6, 3, 6, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 
2, 6, 2, 6, 1, 6, 3, 6, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 2, 6, 6, 3, 6, 
3, 1, 6, 6, 3, 6, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6, 3, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 1, 2, 6, 6, 1, 6, 2, 6, 2, 6, 6, 3, 6, 6, 3, 6, 6, 6, 
3, 1, 6, 6, 2, 6, 3, 3, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 6, 6, 3, 6, 1, 2, 3, 6, 
6, 6, 2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 6, 1, 6, 6, 3, 1, 6, 2, 6, 1, 
6, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 6, 1, 6, 3, 4, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 2, 6, 2, 
6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 6, 1, 6, 6, 6, 1, 6, 2, 6, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 6, 
3, 6, 1, 6, 3, 3, 3, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 2, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 2, 
2, 6, 6, 3, 2, 1, 6, 6, 3, 6, 6, 6, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 6, 1, 6, 
6, 1, 6, 1, 6, 6, 6, 3, 6, 5, 2, 6, 6, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2, 
2, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 6, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 6, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 6, 
2, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 1, 6, 3, 2, 6, 6, 1, 2, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 2, 6, 1, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 1, 6, 6, 6, 3, 6, 6, 1, 
3, 6, 6, 6, 3, 6, 6, 1, 6, 1, 3, 6, 2, 6, 2, 3, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 
1, 3, 6, 2, 2, 6, 6, 1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 6, 2, 6, 3, 6, 6, 
6, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 2, 2, 3, 6, 6, 3, 6, 6, 6, 2, 1, 6, 6, 6, 
1, 6)
```

*Note: The objects are generated by the function dput in R*

Comment: try `library(caret); confusionMatrix(vector2, vector1)` 1 is 1 in both vectors and 3 is 3. 2,4 and 6 are all 6. You can convert group 5 to 2 and group 2 to 5 in the 2nd vector and that's pretty much it. So you would get 1 ~ 1, 2 ~2, 3 ~3, and 4,5,6 ~ 6

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Well, I was expecting that the number of groups agree. Isn't there a way to condition that?

Comment: Check a book (or Wikipedia) on external cluster validation. You are not the first to encounter this problem. People have proposed a dozen measures for this purpose, so don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the rand index measure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index

```
library(fossil)

> rand.index(x, y)
[1] 0.8304887
> adj.rand.index(x,y)
[1] 0.5589514
```

(Here `x` is your first matrix and `y` is your second)

Rand Index calculates the proportion of times that two pairs cluster together or don't cluster together, between `x` and `y`.

Example:

> x: 1,2 ... y: 1,3 ...
>
> This case is +1
>
> x: 1,1 ... y: 2,2 ...
>
> This case is also +1
>
> x: 1,1 ... y: 1,2 ...
>
> This case is 0.

Then divide by total number of pairs.

The adjusted rand index subtracts the proportion that would be obtained just by chance (so adj.rand.index = 0 is random).  In this case, your clustering is doing pretty well.